# How to set/get UIImageView.image through Singleton?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, singleton, uilabel

I have two ViewControllers.

FirstViewController has UILabels and UIImageViews. Also generated a Singleton from its class.
SecondViewController has a call of that Singleton and should GET values of UILabels and UIImageViews from FirstViewController.

NSString works, UILabel do not.

For example, access a **NSString** in SecondviewController with "**sharedFirstViewController.nsstringvarname**" I can GET and SET the value. 
**This works fine!**

Trying the same with an **UILabel** like this: "**sharedFirstViewController.uilabelvar.text**" I doens´t can SET or GET the value of this UILable. 
**This works NOT!**

Is there any special thing with UI-Objects?
Would be great if someone can help me with that.
Thanks!

EDIT:

in FirstViewController.h

```
+ (id)sharedFirstViewController; 
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *path; 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pic;
```

in FirstViewController.m

```
@synthesize path= _path;
@synthesize pic = _pic;


- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  0, 100, 200)];
    }
    return self;
}

    + (id) sharedFirstViewController {
        static sharedFirstViewController * sharedFirstViewController = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedFirstViewController = [[self alloc] init];
        });
        return sharedFirstViewController;
    }
```

in SecondViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

FirstViewController * sharedFirstViewController = [FirstViewController sharedFirstViewController];

NSLog(@"this is NSString from FVC: %@" sharedFirstViewController.path);  //works

UIImage * picture = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:sharedFirstViewController.path];
        sharedFirstViewController.pic.image = picture;     // does´t work

}
```

Comment: code and specific errors will help work out what is wrong

Comment: show you code how do you make singleton class and it varibles

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you forget to give allocation to UIImageview *pic in init method of singleton class. That because your code running but without any crash and warning. If you debug your code you will get imageview memory allocation 0X0. check it.

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
         _pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  0, 100, 200)];
    }
    return self;
}
```

write above method in in FirstViewController.m class. Their is doesn't need of write IBOutlet in front of UIImageView *pic because you not mention your viewcontroller nib while generation singleton instance. Use IBOutlet whenever you dealing UI in xib.

Comment: tried, but doesn´t get it works, too. Why do I need this for UIImageView, and NSString works without this?

Comment: Set breakpoint on sharedFirstViewController.pic.image = picture line trace singlton class variable allocation and print description of pic and show me that debugger output.

Comment: show your code with init method what ever you tried use update question.

Comment: _pic UIImageView * nil 0x00000000

Comment: yes, compiler gave an error for that, so i did this at first time testing your code.  edited question with your init code.

Comment: Frame should be required here. either dynamic yeah static => _pic = [[UIImageView alloc] init] @user2355509

Comment: @user2355509 see my updated answer with frame. I'm trying your scenario i got it work with my given solution, again check your code and try.

Comment: added initWithFrame, but still same issue: _pic UIImageView * nil 0x00000000

Comment: set break point in init method and check _pic line get call or not.

Comment: yes, but still _pic UIImageView * nil 0x00000000  ...thanks for your huge support... at this point i not quit comprehend the solution, especially  because of the working NSString.

Comment: @user2355509 actually it generic problem of allocation of object always developer forget to do. I don't why it not work in your code, but yes i trying same you said in your question it got worked in my code.

Comment: So, another question for that: Setting the Image for pic in FirstViewController like that self.pic.image = picture works. So should´t it be possible to get it´s value in SecondViewController through the singleton "sharedFirstViewController.pic.image" !? ...or maybe is the problem, that the singleton isn´t the same instance, in which pic.image was set in FirstViewController!? ...but also tried to set the pic like this in FirstViewController: sharedFirstViewController.pic.image = picture ...but also with no success!